# Run a shell command on ubuntu/nginx boot

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, boot, mongodb, node.js

I have a ubuntu 13 running nginx and node.js, to start mongodb I need to run on command line:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Problem is that when I exit terminal, it stops, how can I add this to the startup script?

I assume this is the boot scrpit:
http://pastebin.com/raw/ENxuMcpA

Comment: The script is for starting up Node.js server. How did you install your MongoDB?

Comment: I followed this to install mongo:
http://codingtip.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-1304-step-by.html

Comment: so did you follow the documentation for your OS: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As step 5 said in http://codingtip.blogspot.cz/2013/09/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-1304-step-by.html use `service mongodb start` and `sudo service mongodb start` if not root.

If the service doesn't start at boot automatically try to look at `ls -la /etc/rc* | grep mongo`, if no links there are present, then use `update-rc.d mongodb defaults` this should add links to /etc/rc* dirs as said LSB headers in `/etc/init.d/mongodb` init script.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation instructions step 5 tells how to start / stop the service. You just run `sudo service start mongodb` to start the server.

If you want to make the service start up at boot, you can the follow instructions at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup)

`service` command is the standard way of managing services in Debian derived Linux distributions like Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Try install screen. Run on screen. Detach screen. Or run the command. Ctrl+z and press bg to put process on background.

Comment: I only have command line access

Comment: apt-get install screen

Comment: This is not the way to manage services on Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu.